# Pass parameter to a query from another query in Access

Tags: sql, .net, ms-access

I have a parameterized query GET_CUSTOMER:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE id = [customer_id]
```

I want to call this query from another query and pass it a parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM GET_CUSTOMER(123)
```

Note the above code is not valid, it is here to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do. Is it possible to do this in MS Access?

**UPDATE 1:**

The queries I posted are for example. The actual queries are much more complex. I know I can use table joins, but in my specific case it would be much easier if I could run parameterized queries inside other queries (that are parameterized as well). I can't use access forms because I'm using access with my .NET application.

Comment: Why? Both queries will return the same results? I mean the answer is yes. If you open a new query and do  `Select GET_CUSTOMER.* FROM GET_CUSTOMER` it will still ask for the parameter for `id`. So you would pass it as if it was the original query.

Comment: You probably rather want to join the tables.

Comment: Please always include all tags. For example, you should include which particular flavour of .net, in addition to my edit.

Comment: I didn't add .NET because it is irrelevant for my specific problem. My problem is to pass parameter to a query from another query in Access.

Comment: I edited title to correctly state my specific question

Comment: @andr111: QueryDef objects in Access can see the Parameters of the queries they are built on.  Say Query2 is the query that sits on top of GET_CUSTOMER; you can write code similar to this: QueryDefs("Query2").Parameters("customer_id") = 123, even though the param does not belong to the top level.  So the params of the underlying query can therefore be accessed by the higher-level ones (off the top of my head, I don't know what happens if there are identically named parameters in the stack of queries; I think they are all given the same value once the param is set).  So yes, it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I end up solving this with help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/24677391/303463 . It turned out that Access shares parameters among all queries so there is no need to specifically pass parameters from one query to another.

Query1:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID > [param1] AND ID < [param2]
```

Query2:

```
SELECT * FROM Query1
```

VB.NET code:

```
    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=Database.mdb"
    Dim SqlString As String = "Query2"
    Using Conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Using Cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, Conn)
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", "1")
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", "3")
            Conn.Open()
            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Console.WriteLine(reader("ID"))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score -1):

You can build the SQL on the fly.

```
MyID = prompt or get from user some ID

strSQl = "Select * from tblCustomer where ID in " & _
       "(select * from tblTestCustomers where id = " & MyID
```

So you can nest, or use the source of one query to feed a list of ID to the second query.

Comment: I know how to pass parameter from .NET. What I'm trying to understand is whether it is possible to pass a parameter to a query from another query.